# Align images in html column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get 2 columns; the left column with an image and the right column with the text belonging to the image.

I use the `img-circle` class for each image. I want the images to be vertically aligned, however the image seems to show up in its own way.

What is the best method to get 2 columns with about 10 rows, where the first column has an image and the second column contains the text, belonging to the image?

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="assets/images/openhaard_smart_px200_P3150849.jpg" class="img-circle pull-left" width="65" height="65">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h2>Ontvangst bij de openhaard</h2>
  <p>Voel direct de warme gastvrijheid wanneer uw persoonlijke gastvrouw de dag door neemt.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="assets/images/gezichtsbehandeling400px_76174604.jpg" class="img-circle" width="65" height="65"></div>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h2>Gezichtsbehandeling</h2>
  <p>Zeer uitgebreide 75 minuten durende gezichts- en decoleté behandeling in luxe ruime salons 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the code, what causes the dis-alignment
in the first image the class

```
class="img-circle pull-left"
```

is used
in the second image

```
 class="img-circle"
```

this will cause that the first picture is pulled left and the other is centred.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example I have created for you [here](http://www.bootply.com/89UcfYbX0P).

I have only created three rows for you, but you get the picture.

Hope this helps, great question.

Check out [shoelace](http://shoelace.io/) if you're fairly new to bootstrap and looking for a visual representation of how it will look.

Comment: Hi, Toby, the bootply example gives an error to me. Can you look at this?

Comment: It works now, probably an temporary issue with bootply. I've seen your example, but it don't 'circle' the images. However I've changed something what it will make work.   ORIGINAL: <img src="assets/images/openhaard_smart_px200_P3150849.jpg" class="img-circle pull-left" width="65" height="65">
</div>  CHANGE: <img class="img-circle" src="assets/images/openhaard_smart_px200_P3150849.jpg"  width="65" height="65">
</div>